# Inserting seconds into a database in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: mysql, time, insert

I have a JavaScript timer on a PHP page. It returns a number, representing seconds, that I want to insert into a database column of type `Time`. How can I do that?

This code is the best I could find:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO #__quiz_r_student_question (c_stu_quiz_id,
                                                  c_question_id,
                                                  c_score,
                                                  c_attempts,
                                                  is_correct,
                                                  time_to_solve
                                                 )" .
         "\n VALUES('".$stu_quiz_id."',
                    '".$quest_id."',
                    '".$c_quest_score."',
                    '".($c_quest_cur_attempt + 1)."',
                    '".$is_correct."',
                    DATEADD(ms, ".$time_to_solve."* 1000, 0)
                   )";
```

Comment: There is no standard SQL way to do what you want to do.  This is something which varies depending on the DBMS you're using, so you should probably tell us which one you're using.

Comment: What database platform are you using?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?  Btrieve?

Comment: Also, watch out for that SQL Injection vulnerability you have there...

Comment: Well it's all data retrieved from the DB and not from the user, is it still vulnerabul to SQL Injection?

Comment: Sure, if someone else has permission to put things in your database.

Comment: If you're inserting something into the database without [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) then you're (at least *potentially*) vulnerable to SQL injection. Obligatory [SQL-injection XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/), and link to further reading [on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we don't typically update questions with the eventual solutions. Please post your fix as an answer instead. That way, you can accept it, which is semantically good, and you're more likely to get reputation because other users can judge the question and answer separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer was originally posted by the asker as an edit to the question.*

I solved my problem with PHP, not an SQL query. I used this code to change my seconds value into a readable time ready for database insertion:

```
$time = gmdate('H:i:s',$time_to_solve)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function. Take a look at this script -

```
CREATE TABLE table_time(
  column1 TIME DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_time VALUES(SEC_TO_TIME(3600));

SELECT * FROM table_time;
+----------+
| column1  |
+----------+
| 01:00:00 |
+----------+
```